# Ubuntu 17.04 GeForceGTX 960 nvidia driver ... login loop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, cuda

Please, which nvidia driver version will not land me in infinity login loop?
I was reading tons of similar questions but not a single solution works for me.

The system info and xerrors:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24407648/

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24407652/

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24407657/

My update history (today I was trying to get the system working, but a week ago it was working 100%):

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24407674/

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24407685/

login as guest - can be done

login as any user - cannot be done, just displays the login screen again (somtime with brief nvidia logo flash)

login as anything after purge nvidia* - can be done

Was it working before - Yes! I was doing cuda computing on some version of 375 driver (and I would love to do it again :) ).

Thank You very much!

M.

Comment: As of right now, it seems that `nvidia-375` is not compatible with 17.04.  Attempting to install it gives `xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable` it sounds like your old installation was left in an inconsistent state.  I think you'll have to just wait.

Comment: Wow I did install it without any problems... I did encounter this bug in 16.10, then tried switching nvidia drivers, booting from older linux versions using grub and then finally tried to upgrade my system to 17.04. .... Anyway there is some more info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24418401/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the [Proprietary Driver Repository](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for Ubuntu is enabled and then install the latest stable driver, as shown below:

1. Add the repository to your system, and update your source lists:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install nvidia-381 --install-recommends -y
   ```

And then reboot to test the changes:

```
sudo systemctl reboot
```

And a small tip with CUDA: Do not install it from the provided repository by Nvidia. Instead, download the binary blob in full (about 1 GB?), make it executable, run the installer as root, follow the prompts, accept the defaults **BUT DO NOT INSTALL THE BUNDLED DEVICE DRIVER! THIS IS IMPORTANT!**

When done, set up the environment variables for CUDA:

Edit the `/etc/environment` file and append the following:

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-8.0
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
```

Then reboot.

Test that your GPU is working by running:

```
nvidia-smi -q
```

After logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "acpi_osi=" in grub.

In terminal first

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then edit line starts with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and add "acpi_osi=", like this below

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Then update grub with

```
sudo grub-update
```

and restart. This worked for me and hopefully for you too. I was unable to use linux for a long time on my asus n552vx laptop and finally able to use Ubuntu 17.04 gnome with nvidia driver installed.

*Note: "acpi=off" also works but for me touchpad and function key was not working.*